# Run javascript on HTML generated from C# string

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I would like to run javascript on HTML generated from C# string.
(without opening browser - just C# code)

Something like:

```
string myHTML = '<div id="divTest">This is test<br/><br/></div>';
```

Javascript should be:

```
function test 
{
     return document.getElementById('divTest').offsetHeight;
}
```

What I've already tried is check some headless browsers like PhantomJS and Optimus - but they don't have an option to render string (only to open web page through web address like `http://google.com/`. Is there a way to achieve this through C#?

Comment: Are you appending string myHTML to your page HTML. This should be accessible from any browser.

Comment: if the html is placed in dom as html, it should be accessible

Comment: This is not entirely clear. You want to run javascript on a string of HTML, and get the height of the element.... outside a browser, i.e. in something like a command-line tool etc?

Comment: I've edited question - without opening browser, of course.

Comment: *but they don't have an option to render string* - what do you mean by this?

Comment: The only option they have is to open web page through web address.

Comment: The 'offsetHeight' property is render-time value. Headless browsers by their nature can not evaluate these properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is working for me:

```
string html = "<html><head></head><body><div id=\"divTest\">This is test<br/><br/></div></body></html>";

string script1 = "return document.getElementById('divTest').innerText";
string script2 = "return document.getElementById('divTest').offsetHeight";

var options = new PhantomJSOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("javascriptEnabled", true);

var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(options);
driver.Url = "file://dummy.html";
driver.Navigate();
driver.ExecutePhantomJS("document.write('" + html + "');");

var test1 = driver.ExecutePhantomJS(script1);
//Returns: This is a test
var test2 = driver.ExecutePhantomJS(script2);
//Returns: 40
```

You need to install the Selenium.WebDriver NuGet and to download the PhantomJS exe from http://phantomjs.org/download.html it needs to be in the same folder as your exe or in the PATH.

Comment: I would like to run javascript without opening browser. Just C# code.

Comment: Do you have any example on this? Or link?

Comment: I added an example, haven't tested it myself but should work or at least get you in the right direction ;-)

Comment: I managed to make it work with a few tweaks, I edited the answer.

Comment: Your solution is good. The only thing which I don't know is how to set global variable for driver in MVC? I want to open PhantomJSDriver and keep it open (because this is much faster than open - close each time). It's not a problem to do this in windows application, but what about MVC?